# Regular Expression Sub Problems

Tags: python, regex

Okay so i have a semi weridish problem with re.sub.

Take the following code:

```
import re
str_to_be_subbed = r'somefile.exe -i <INPUT>'
some_str = r'C:\foobar'
s = re.sub(r'\<INPUT\>', some_str, str_to_be_subbed)
print s
```

I would think it would give me:

```
somefile.exe -i C:\\foobar
```

But instead it gives me:

```
somefile.exe -i C:♀oobar
```

I know \f is an escape char, but even if i try to do it this way, which should escape the special characthers. Even if i do this:

```
print r'%s' % s
```

It still gives me this:

```
somefile.exe -i C:♀oobar
```

Why does it do this? And whats the best way to avoid this?

Ninja Edit:

If i look at the value of s it is:

```
'somefile.exe -i C:\x0coobar'
```

Why did \f turn into \x0. Ugh.

Edit:

One more question, if i modify the code to this:

```
import re
import os
str_to_be_subbed = r'somefile.exe -i <INPUT>'
some_str = os.path.abspath(r'C:\foobar')
some_str
s = re.sub(r'\<INPUT\>', some_str, str_to_be_subbed)
print s
```

Gives me:

```
>>> import re
>>> import os
>>> str_to_be_subbed = r'somefile.exe -i <INPUT>'
>>> some_str = os.path.abspath(r'C:\foobar')
>>> some_str
'C:\\foobar'
>>> s = re.sub(r'\<INPUT\>', some_str, str_to_be_subbed)
>>> print s
somefile.exe -i C:♀oobar
```

Now why is that. Since os.path.abspath escapes the \'s. Why does re.sub still mess up?

Also this is a really small example, of this little problem that just cropped up randomly in an oldish application. I can't really go and change this to string.replace because of how its setup without spending a whole day.

I am just really curious as to why it is doing this. For the above problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\f` is the *form feed* character. Escape it and it works:

```
some_str = r'C:\\foobar'
```

Another solution:

```
s = re.sub(r'<INPUT>', some_str.encode("string_escape"), str_to_be_subbed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regular expressions:

```
print str_to_be_subbed.replace("<INPUT>",some_str)
```

As the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) says:

> repl can be a string or a function; if
>   it is a string, any backslash escapes
>   in it are processed.

Comment: I cannot use string replace. 

I have to use the regex form otherwise i will be forced to change/modify hundreds of lines of someone elses code.

Answer (score 2):

Python docs saying...

re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes such as \j are left alone

This is why it gives 'C:♀oobar'.

but if we give it a function as the second argument, it doesn't convert any backslash escapes.

So try following..

```
>>>import re
>>>str_to_be_subbed = r'somefile.exe -i <INPUT>'
>>>some_str = r'C:\foobar'
>>>s = re.sub(r'\<INPUT\>', lambda _:some_str, str_to_be_subbed)
>>>print s
somefile.exe -i c:\foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't need regexps, use [`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> str_to_be_subbed.replace('<INPUT>',some_str)
'somefile.exe -i C:\\foobar'
>>>
```